# padding is not equal?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a *perfect* circle on the font awesome icon when hovered with tailwindcss but the circle's height is too long so it looks like a vertical oval. I think the top and bottom padding is not equal as the left and right padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <i class="hover:bg-gray-300 hover:rounded-full p-2 fa-solid fa-close"></i>
  </body>
</html>
```

**please try to use tailwindcss, no style tags.**

Answer (score 0):

Just set manually the `width` and `height` of the icon:

```html
<i class="w-8 h-8 hover:bg-gray-300 hover:rounded-full p-2 fa-solid fa-close"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<i>` tag is an inline element. You can add space to the left and right on an inline element, but you cannot add height to the top or bottom padding or margin of an inline element. It's better to add a wrapper on  tag and use padding on wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div-wrapper and change the alignment accordingly. Please see the below implementation.

You can change the *ico* with any icon.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="w-20 h-20 p-7 m-5 hover:bg-gray-300 hover:rounded-full fa-solid fa-close bg-lime-300 rounded-full">
<i >ico</i>
</div>
```